# How to show the data user is filling in a form in html side by side on the same html page?

Tags: php, jquery, html

I am very new to web designing. I want to create a web page such that when the user is typing in the form, at the same moment that data must be shown on the left side of the same page as in the image below. Example, as the user types in the about me text box, the data area on the left side with about me title should also get updated instantly and dynamically with the same speed the user is typing.

Can anyone please help me how this is possible? or which language will i have to use to do this?
thanks in advance.

[example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cfIXb.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to use javascript to achieve this.

```
<input type="text" id="input">
<div id="output">

</div>

<script>
    var input = document.getElementById('input');
    var output = document.getElementById('output');
    // add event listener to the input element
    input.onkeyup= function() {
        // set the output element HTML to what you type in
        output.innerHTML = this.value;
    }
</script>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/124485/

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code :

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">  </script>
          <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('#name').keyup(function () {
                    $('#display').text($(this).val());
                });
            });
          </script>
        </head>
         <body>
          <input type="text" id="name"/>
          <span id="display"></span>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: Do you really need jQuery to do this?

Comment: I saw the tag of jQuery so I answered jQuery code snippet to perform that task... You can do the same task with only Javascript using it's keyup event..

Comment: Right, fair enough.